# User login and stay logged in with phonegap app?

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, cordova, oauth

I'm building a mobile app for my website using Phonegap and I am using PHP Codeigniter framework to create my REST API. I need to allow users to log in to the app and retrieve information but I am little confused on the authentication part.

Right now this is what I have in mind:

- User logs in with username/password (they will be send to the server using HTTPS)
- My API will check the db to see if the user exists
- If the user exists generate a random string (token) and send it back to client
- On the client side (mobile app), store the token somewhere
- Every time user requests information from the server, send the token for validation

I decided to go with token method because I needed to allow users to stay logged in to the app once they login for the first time (I read that storing username/password on client side is bad).

So here are my questions,

Is my method valid/safe? If so how is token stored on phonegap? Will localStorage do the job?

Is there a better & simpler method?

Are there libraries that could help me do this easier/faster? especially with building REST API?

Lastly, I heard about OAuth2 but is this only for when you want to allow 3rd party logins (google, facebook etc)? I've looked into it and there seems to be an OAuth for PHP and OAuth for Phonegap. If I implement this, will I need to do it in my REST API AND phonegap side?

I'm fairly new to all this so any explanations with examples will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use your token method.Every time app launches check the localstorage for user token is set if not set up http request and store the token in localstorage.
Here is sample code

```
function validateUser(username,password){
  //get the user token from local storage
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null){
           //set up the http request
            $.ajax({
              url:'www.example.com/login.php',
              method:post,
              data:{'username':username,'password':password}
              success:function(data){
                 //set the token in localstorage
                 window.localStorage.setItem('usertoken',data);

              }
           });
       }
      }  
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. i had the same question.. however im wondering whats to stop anyone from just storing a random string in local storage to pretend they are logged in?

Comment: Use JSON web tokens to create tokens rather than a random string